# Extract overlapping names from different data sets (character)

Tags: r

Is there any easy way to find overlapping names from different data sets ?

```
> class(list1)
[1] "character"
```

So let's say that I have a data like that:

```
list1 <- c("Mark", "Greg", "Max", "Gregor", "Paul", "JAck", "Marcus")
list2 <- c("Chris", "Jackson", "Mark", "Michael", "Gena", "Greg")
list3 <- c("Susane", "Mark", "Monica", "Chistopher", "Henry", "Atos", "Greg")
list4 <- c("Peter", "Marie", "Mark", "Greg", "Denice", "Daryl", "Maros", "Gert", "Suar")
```

The only names which are in all data are:

```
Mark and Greg
```

How to find such overlapping using R ? My data is much bigger so that's why I use an example.

Comment: Edited, did a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Reduce(intersect, list(list1, list2, list3, list4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `qdap` approach if `list4` does indeed contain `Mark`:

```
library(qdap)
common(list1, list2, list3, list4)

## > common(list1, list2, list3, list4)
##   word freq
## 1 Greg    4
## 2 Mark    4
```